# I want to create an expression that adds the elements in the list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create an expression that adds all the elements of the list to 1.

```
m={Subscript[p, 0, 3], Subscript[p, 1, 2], Subscript[p, 1, 3], \
Subscript[p, 2, 1], Subscript[p, 2, 2], Subscript[p, 2, 3], \
Subscript[p, 3, 0], Subscript[p, 3, 1], Subscript[p, 3, 2], \
Subscript[p, 3, 3], Subscript[p, 4, 0], Subscript[p, 4, 1], \
Subscript[p, 4, 2], Subscript[p, 5, 0], Subscript[p, 5, 1], \
Subscript[p, 6, 0]}
```

I want to do this.

```
m={Subscript[p, 0, 3]+ Subscript[p, 1, 2]+ Subscript[p, 1, 3]+ \
Subscript[p, 2, 1]+ Subscript[p, 2, 2]+ Subscript[p, 2, 3]+ \
Subscript[p, 3, 0]+ Subscript[p, 3, 1]+ Subscript[p, 3, 2]+ \
Subscript[p, 3, 3]+ Subscript[p, 4, 0]+ Subscript[p, 4, 1]+ \
Subscript[p, 4, 2]+ Subscript[p, 5, 0]+ Subscript[p, 5, 1]+ \
Subscript[p, 6, 0]==1}
```

Please teach an efficient method, I wish.

Comment: Have a look at `Total`.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher 　Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try this form:

```
Plus @@ m == 1
```